# clojure, using a list of functions

Tags: clojure

I would like to define a list of functions to use within juxt, however I am having trouble implementing it.

Heres an example of what I want:

```
(defn sin [n] (Math/sin n))
(defn cos [n] (Math/cos n))
((juxt sin cos) 4)
>> [-0.7568024953079282 -0.6536436208636119]
```

Now instead of saying `((juxt sin cos) 4)` I would prefer to say `((juxt trig) 4)` where 
`(def trig [sin cos])`. I have attempted `((apply juxt trig) 4)` and a few other things but nothing seems to stick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply` seems to work fine:

```
user=> ((juxt sin cos) 4)
[-0.7568024953079282 -0.6536436208636119]
user=> ((apply juxt trig) 4)
[-0.7568024953079282 -0.6536436208636119]
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a correct solution. For me it works:

```
Clojure 1.2.1
user=> (defn sin [n] (Math/sin n))
#'user/sin
user=> (defn cos [n] (Math/cos n))
#'user/cos
user=> (def trig [sin cos])
#'user/trig
user=> ((apply juxt trig) 4)
[-0.7568024953079282 -0.6536436208636119]
```